# How do i get syntax highlighting for a Jslib file in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I tried the WebGL tutorial by [Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) and everything worked well.

But the jslib file does not appear in Visuals Studio (I placed it in the "Plugins" folder), the JS syntax is not highlighted and also I don't have IntelliSense.

How do I get Visual Studio to recognize this file?

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension

Type `jslib` in the Extension field, and select `JavaScript Editor` in the Editor's dropdown field. Then, click on the Add button.

[image: Give highlighting syntax to jslib file in Visual Studio]

Comment: You may also have to restart to see it recognized